# How do I set a menu in OCDI

Tags: theme-development

I want to use the [OCDI plugin](https://ocdi.com/) to export a demo. That works, except for the menu. Whatever I try, I have to set it manually after import.

This is the code:

```
    // Assign menus to their locations.
    $main_menu = get_term_by( 'name', 'Main Menu', 'nav_menu' );
 
    set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', [
            'main-menu' => $main_menu->term_id, // replace 'main-menu' here with the menu location identifier from register_nav_menu() function in your theme.
        ]
    );
```

My menu is named **main-menu**. I tried several variations, but so far no go. What am I doing wrong?